# WebStorm doesn't recognize AngularJS 'vm' variable

Tags: webstorm

I am currently using the AngularJS plugin. It's really helpful.

The only downside is that it doesn't recognize the `vm` variable.

I use these settings in my directive to use the `vm` variable in my view:

```
controllerAs: 'vm',
bindToController: true
```

However, WebStorm doesn't recognize it and gives this error:

[image]

Comment: Are you defining the controller in the template using ng-controller="myControllerName as vm"?

Comment: No I am not doing that

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested with both WebStorm and IntelliJ with the AngularJS plugin and in both cases the templates that include the ng-controller directive in their root element recognize the variable in the template and those without it do not. I would suggest adding it to your template to solve the problem.

```
<div ng-controller="commitmentController as cc">
    <div class="margin-top-bottom">
        <a ui-sref="commitmentList" ng-click="cc.sessionManager.okToContinueWithUnsavedChanges()"
           role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">
           </span>Back to All Commitments
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Rest of template here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I do not really like the idea of altering my code to satisfy my IDE. Anyways, I just found out that this is a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20676

Comment: That is a fair stance to take. We didn't do it to satisfy the IDE, we did it to improve the readability of the code and improve maintainability. It just happens to avoid the specific problem you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Webstorm. See @tokkov his answer for a possible workaround.

See the bug in the issue tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20676